# How the Android Notification Mechanism Works Based On the App's Notification Settings

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

As we know the Android OS will manage every notification of the app and shows the notification even if the app is not running, my question is how an Android app's internal notification settings is synced with the Android OS to manage which notifications to show and which ones to block (mute)?

Is it like the OS will pass the received notification to the intended app and then it decides - based on its internal settings- which one to show? Or the app will give the user-defined notification settings to the OS (by some API or ...) and then OS filters the notifications and decides what to show or not?

Comment: Notifications in Android are managed through collaboration between apps and the operating system. Apps define their own notification settings and channels, and users can customize preferences for each app. The Android OS respects user preferences and system policies like Do Not Disturb mode. When generating notifications, apps consider their internal settings, and the OS determines how notifications are displayed based on user choices and system rules. This ensures a balance between app customization and user control over notifications.

Answer (score 1):

> my question is how an Android app's internal notification settings is synced with the Android OS to manage which notifications to show and which ones to block (mute)?

Android itself does not have a concept of "internal notification settings".

All notifications from an app are created by the app and handed to the OS via `NotificationManager`. The OS then applies system rules for how they should be handled, such as those configured by the user via the system Settings app.

If an app *also* has its own concept of "internal notification settings", that would control when the app actually invokes `NotificationManager`.

> Is it like the OS will pass the received notification to the intended app and then it decides - based on its internal settings- which one to show? Or the app will give the user-defined notification settings to the OS (by some API or ...) and then OS filters the notifications and decides what to show or not?

Neither of those are correct.

Comment: Do you have more information or some detailed documents how it works? I need to have deeper understanding how it works! @CommonsWare

Comment: @MohsenEmami: I am uncertain what "it" is. There is [documentation on `NotificationManager` and notifications](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications?hl=en).

Comment: Your answer was good but not complete and it did not satisfy me base on my ambiguities, so I needed some detailed documents like what you sent in the last comment. Thanks for that! @CommonsWare